# Mozilla-libnss failed to find the certificate

Tags: linux, ssl, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04, mozilla

Can anyone please help me to fix the below issue?

I am using `libnss` to implement tls connection between a server and a client,
Both are being run on a single machine.

First I tried to run `./certutil exe`, I got the below output on console

> Certificate Nickname              Trust Attributes
>                                     SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

Then I tried running the server that is `./selfserv` , but I got one error shown below, here -n (nickname) I am passing as SSL.

Is that right ? or what exactly going wrong here?

**selfserv: Can't find certificate SSL**

Also please explain me how to execute the server and client using mozilla nss with simple steps

Comment: What server and client software are you using?  How are you configuring them?

Comment: I am using the sample server and client given by the nss.

Comment: I downloaded the source code and compiled on my ubuntu 14.04 machine. It automatically create a directory named dist (which contain the include files, libs and binaries).

Comment: I have created a self signed certificate and key using certutil exe and now I am able to run my server and it is up. But when I run the client I see the error message saying  "tstclnt: authentication of server cert failed: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN: Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate" . Please help me to fix the issue